# Handle SQL recursion for multiple pallets and production runs

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I need to trace the costs of production runs and apportion back to the original received pallets. However, once the original pallets goes through a production run, they are mixed with all the other input pallets from that production run and they create multiple output pallets. Those output pallets in theory could be sold OR go back into another production run and come out again as completely different pallets and this process can repeat itself an unknown number of times. The table structure also adds a layer of complication. All of the pallets are created in one table.
[Basic Hierarchal Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbWDq.png)

The Pallets table includes two types:

- N: The originally received Pallet
- P: Pallet produced from a Production run and ProdOrd field is populated with the Run Number

Every time I try to build out the CTE recursion for this scenario, I run into a indefinite loop of the recursion because it is a many to many relationship. I'm thinking that SQL server can't handle it at this level. We have thousands of original pallets and then they get mixed in the shuffle.

What I'm hoping for is something like this:

| Pallet | CostType | Cost | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Run | 3.00 | N |
| 1234 | Labeling | 0.25 | N |
| 1235 | Run | 3.00 | N |
| 1235 | Labeling | 0.25 | N |

The cost is the Sum of all the production runs apportioned to the original input pallet.

Comment: hi, could you provide a simple minimal reproducible example of what is the input data to the table and what your expectation of the output should look like

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at the recursive CTE, table schema and sample data (not images, but cut & pasteable text). Ideally, if you could also load them all into a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-), it would give us something to work with. I believe a recursive CTE may be doable as long as pallet usage follows a non-looping directed graph.

Comment: definitely would help to have sample data, a text table in your question will do or create a fiddle as suggested

Comment: Thanks, I built out a basic version of this here: [https://dbfiddle.uk/YDJeUdSZ](https://dbfiddle.uk/YDJeUdSZ). Figure I could do the costing allocation outside the recursion, but I don't know how to get the original pallet through the recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. I will take a look, but might not get back right away. Looking at your sample data, I do see two anomalies that might need a double check. (1) Pallet 30204 appears to be both an input and output for run 302. (2) if I ignore pallet 30204, the outputs from run 302 exceeds the inputs.

Comment: My initial thoughts are that for each run/lot combination, we can calculate consumption and residual ratios. That could then be used to calculate the presumed fraction of each input pallet distributed to each output pallet at each step. That might then be used in a recursive CTE to calculate the overall propagation of the source pallet inventory through to each destination. Still thinking it through though.

Comment: A possible bug in your current query: Should the second half of your CTE be recursively joining to the prior cte.OutputPallet instead of cte.Inputpallet? That together with eliminating the feedback loop from pallet 30204 will at least allow your query to complete without hitting max recursion.

Comment: Take a look at [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YqA_pLMB). I think I have captured the intent up to the point where the recursive CTE calculates the propagation of pallet contents through the various process runs. (This is probably way more than whet you would normally get from SO, but I thought the problem was an interesting challenge.) It is somewhat over-engineered in that several intermediate calculations are not really used. Feel free to ask questions if you have them, but I'll leave it to you to strip it down, enhance it, or otherwise adapt to your needs if you wish.

Comment: Hey T N, sorry, I didn't see this response till this morning. This is incredible. There is a lot to unpack here, so let me give it a lookover and see how the math works out, and possibly import this solution into my larger dataset. This might take me some time, but if it does works out, I'm going to owe you big time.

Comment: Wow TN, it worked. I ran into a few problems like our pallet numbers can repeat, I was wrong about it being the PK. Either way, was able to work through those issues. Post your answer, and I can accept that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JVR - Done, with a bit of added commentary. One added suggestion: Be sure to thoroughly document whatever you end up with as a courtesy to whomever may need to figure this out years down the road.  Also, if not too much to ask, would you care to share what your product is? I was trying to imagine a process that would load, partially use, and then return to inventory pallets of materials. My two best guesses were cardboard box blanks or electronic components for a PCB pick-and-place process. My money is placed on "I'm not even close".

Comment: @TN - The industry is Produce. Although multiple production runs are not desired, it can happen and multiple times. Cleaning and packing an actively decaying product can change it's quality within days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have captured the intent up to the point where the recursive CTE calculates the propagation of pallet contents through the various process runs.

In order to calculate the propagation of pallet content through the entire production series, we must first calculate the propagation from each input pallet to each output pallet at each step. That calculation turns out to be a non-trivial combination of quantity per input pallet, total input by lot, total output by lot, and quantity per output pallet.

The following is what I came up with across several steps.

First, calculate input and output totals for each production run and lot. We will need these values in the calculations of the following step

```
CREATE TABLE #InOutQty(
  ProdOrd NVARCHAR(10), Lot NVARCHAR(12),
  InTotalQty INT, OutTotalQty INT,
  PassThroughFraction FLOAT, ConsumedFraction FLOAT
)
  
INSERT #InOutQty
    SELECT IQ.ProdOrd, IQ.Lot, IQ.InTotalQty, ISNULL(OQ.OutTotalQty, 0),
        A1.PassThroughFraction,
        (1e0 - A1.PassThroughFraction) AS ConsumedFraction
    FROM (
       -- Total up inputs by production run and lot
       SELECT I.ProdOrd, P.Lot, Sum(I.QTY) AS InTotalQty
       FROM ProdInput I
       JOIN Pallets P ON P.Pallet = I.Pallet
       GROUP BY I.ProdOrd, P.Lot
    ) IQ
    LEFT JOIN(
       -- Total up inputs by production run and lot (might be none for certain inputs) 
       SELECT P.ProdOrd, P.Lot, Sum(P.OrgQTY) AS OutTotalQty
       FROM Pallets P
       WHERE P.Type = 'P'
       GROUP BY P.ProdOrd, P.Lot
    ) OQ
        ON OQ.ProdOrd = IQ.ProdOrd
        AND OQ.Lot = IQ.Lot
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Calculate how much is unused and repacked on a new pallet 
        SELECT (1e0 * ISNULL(OQ.OutTotalQty, 0) / IQ.InTotalQty) AS PassThroughFraction
    ) A1
```

Next calculate the input and output attributable to each combination of production run, input, and output pallets. Leftover materials from multiple input pallets of the same lot are assumed to be mixed evenly and reallocated to the output pallets.

```
CREATE TABLE #PalletInOutQty (
    ProdOrd NVARCHAR(10), Lot NVARCHAR(12),
    InputPallet NVARCHAR(12), OutputPallet NVARCHAR(12),
    InputQty FLOAT, OutputQty FLOAT,
    InputPalletFraction FLOAT, PassThroughFraction FLOAT
)
  
INSERT #PalletInOutQty
SELECT IOQ.ProdOrd, IOQ.Lot, IP.Pallet, OP.Pallet,
    A1.InputQty,
    (A1.InputQty * IOQ.PassThroughFraction) AS OutputQty,
    (A1.InputQty * 1e0 / IP.OrgQty) AS InputPalletFraction,
    IOQ.PassThroughFraction
FROM #InOutQty IOQ
JOIN ProdInput PI ON PI.ProdOrd = IOQ.ProdOrd
JOIN Pallets IP ON IP.Pallet = PI.Pallet AND IP.Lot = IOQ.Lot
JOIN Pallets OP ON OP.ProdOrd = IOQ.ProdOrd AND OP.Lot = IOQ.Lot
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Input quantity for this in/out pallet combination is calculated as the
    -- the selected input pallet qty times the fraction of the total output
    -- included in the selected output pallet.
    SELECT (PI.Qty * (OP.OrgQty * 1e0 / IOQ.OutTotalQty)) AS InputQty
) A1
```

Now we can use a recursive CTE to retrieve the initial pallet information, and for each pallet, follow the path through the production run to calculate how the content of that original pallet propagates through the series.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PalletLineage') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PalletLineage
CREATE TABLE #PalletLineage (
    Pallet NVARCHAR(12),
    OriginPallet NVARCHAR(12),
    Lineage NVARCHAR(1000),
    Qty FLOAT,
    OriginPalletFraction FLOAT
)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        P.Pallet,
        P.Pallet AS OriginPallet, 
        CAST(P.Pallet AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Lineage,
        CAST(P.OrgQty AS Float) AS Qty,
        1.0e0 AS OriginPalletFraction
    FROM Pallets P
    WHERE P.Type = 'N'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        PIOQ.OutputPallet AS Pallet,
        cte.OriginPallet AS OriginPallet,
        CONCAT(cte.Lineage, ' > ', PIOQ.OutputPallet) AS Lineage,
        (cte.Qty / P.OrgQty * PIOQ.OutputQty) AS Qty,
        (cte.OriginPalletFraction * PIOQ.InputPalletFraction
            * PIOQ.PassThroughFraction) AS OriginPalletFraction
    FROM cte
    JOIN #PalletInOutQty PIOQ ON PIOQ.InputPallet = cte.Pallet
    JOIN pallets P ON P.Pallet = cte.Pallet
)
INSERT #PalletLineage
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x67FXpDH) for a demo.

This is somewhat over-engineered in that several intermediate calculations are not really used. Feel free to ask questions if you have them, but I'll leave it to you to strip it down, enhance it, or otherwise adapt to your needs if you wish.

Applying additional steps to apply cost calculations is left as a follow-up exercise.